# Movable QRubberband from one point to another

Tags: qt, rubber-band, qmouseevent

I have drawn a QRubberband on QLabel. i can resize it using QSizeGrip. Now I want to move it from one point to another using QMouseevents. Is there any one who can help me out.

```
void CropImage::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QLabel::mousePressEvent(event);
    lastPoint = event->pos();
    rubberband = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle,this);
    rubberband->setGeometry(QRect(lastPoint, QSize()));
    rubberband->show();

}

void CropImage::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    newPoint = event->pos();
}
```

this is my subclass part which is used for mouse events. the code is as following:

```
Resizable_rubber_band::Resizable_rubber_band(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
 //tell QSizeGrip to resize this widget instead of top-level window
 setWindowFlags(Qt::SubWindow);
 QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
 layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
 QSizeGrip* grip1 = new QSizeGrip(this);
 QSizeGrip* grip2 = new QSizeGrip(this);
 layout->addWidget(grip1, 0, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
 layout->addWidget(grip2, 0, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignBottom);
 rubberband = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
 rubberband->move(0, 0);
 rubberband->show();
}

 void Resizable_rubber_band::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *)
 {
    rubberband->resize(size());
 }

 void Resizable_rubber_band::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {
    lastPoint = event->pos();
    rubberband->childAt(lastPoint);
 }

 void Resizable_rubber_band::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {
   newpoint = event->pos();
   int dragx=newpoint.x()-lastPoint.x();
   int dragy=newpoint.y()-lastPoint.y();
   band->move(0+dragx,0+dragy);
 }
```

In this code, my problem is i am not getting the exact coordinates after dragging

thanks.

Ashish

Comment: A detailed description of what the problem is would help a lot.

Comment: I want to move that rubberband using mousepressevent. How can i do it ?

Comment: how do i know the mouseevent is on rubberband or somewhere else on the application ? please elaborate it.

Comment: Thanks Thuga, I have already tried it. its works fine but when i try to drag the rubberband using mouse, it deletes my rubberband. I am not able to drag my rubberband.

Comment: hey thuga, I have edited my query. now you can check my code and tell me please what should i do to get the exact cordinates.

Comment: Can you please give me a dummy code for this, i am getting confused in this. Your help will really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example I made where you can move a `QRubberBand` using mouse events:

***mainwindow.h***

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QRubberBand>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QRubberBand *rubberBand;
    bool move_rubberband;
    QPoint rubberband_offset;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

***mainwindow.cpp***

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    move_rubberband = false;
    rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
    rubberBand->setGeometry(0,0,50,50);
    rubberBand->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if(rubberBand->geometry().contains(e->pos()))
    {
        rubberband_offset = e->pos() - rubberBand->pos();
        move_rubberband = true;
    }
}

void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if(move_rubberband)
    {
        rubberBand->move(e->pos() - rubberband_offset);
    }
}

void MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    move_rubberband = false;
}
```

Comment: but i am not able to resize it properly using my upper code in which i am using QSizeGrips.

Comment: @Ashish What does "not able to resize it properly" mean? What happens?

Comment: when i am trying to drag the rubberband from one point to another,only rubberband is moving but QSizeGrip is not moving(its fixed).

Comment: @Ashish Well of course. If you're not moving them, why would you expect them to move? Either move them separately, or create a widget that contains the rubber band and the size grips.